# Почему он сразу не обновляется?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

```js
var header = document.querySelector('.navbar-header');

window.onload = function (){

 if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 755px)").matches) {
   header.style.height =  '98px';
 } else {
   header.style.height =  'auto';
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
         <!--  <div class="line"></div> -->
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Heshimovnotes</span>
              <img src="img/notes.png" alt="Brand" class="hidden-lg hidden-md logo">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">punkt 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">punkt 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
  
  
   <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Вопрос такой.Написал такой хедер.Высота 98 пикселей при  ширине 755 иначе автоматизированный(50 пикселей).Ну вот не понимаю почему при  уменьшении дисплея в браузере оно  не меняет размер?Нужно обновить страничку чтобы получить   результат.можно ли это решить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что проверка ширины и установка высоты хэдера происходят при загрузке страницы - в `window.onload`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function CheckWidth() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 755px)").matches) {
      $('.navbar-header').css("background-color", 'red');
    } else {
      $('.navbar-header').css("background-color", 'green');
    }
  }

  $(window).resize(CheckWidth);
  CheckWidth();
});
```

```css
.navbar-header
{
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-header"></div>
```

Comment: ваш код не валидный.

Comment: код хороший, Вы его просто неаккуратно скопировали :)

Comment: вот пожалуйста сами смотрите https://jsfiddle.net/cktu55kz/ оно не меняет размер с 50 на 98 пикселей при маленькой ширине.Может вы неправильно поняли вопрос. :(

Comment: @DuuudeXX8 https://jsfiddle.net/cktu55kz/1/

Comment: уже работает спасибо.

Comment: вы просто в коде забыли поставить  var header = document.querySelector('.navbar-header'); а так без него не знаю как вообще вы хотели чтобы это заработало.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вообще городить JS? Не проще ли решить эту задачу на CSS

```
.navbar-header {
  height: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 755px) {
  .navbar-header {
    height: 98px;
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо конечно за ответ.Но даже самые маленькие изменение нужно писать с помощью скриптов.